# Javascript try/catch not catching errors

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have a function like so

```
const myFunction = async function (arg1,arg2) {

**update**
I am casting arg2 into a variable called 'command'

const command = arg2 as {
      api_base_url: string
      session_id: string      
    }
**end of update**

try {
const url = `${command.api_base_url}/rest/api/latest/projects/`
const getData= await axios.get(url)
}
catch (error) {
    context.log(error)
  }
}
```

When I pass an empty object as `arg2`, it means that `url` variable is never created and hence `get` request is never made.

However, no error is thrown! How to make sure there is an error when `arg2` is empty of `url` variable cannot be created?

I though `try/catch` would automatically do this but I guess my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: "_url variable is never created_" Incorrect, the created URL is `undefined/rest/api/latest/projects/`. You can check `arg2.api_base_url` has a value before using it.

Comment: @Teemu I am casting `arg2` into a variable called `command` with types defined (I am using TS) will this also not throw as error?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in an empty object as arg2 the URL would be `undefined/rest/api/latest/projects` and the request would be made to that url.